# codeigniter wkhtmltopdf intro

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, wkhtmltopdf

Can anyone help me? I want to show a printable report in pdf for a calendar report in my codeigniter. The calendar uses a jquery library called fullcalendar. Recently I used mpdf to create my pdf reports. But when I used it on my calendar, it didn't displayed the calendar, though the rest of the page did get called. I wanted to use this wkhtmltopdf that everyone recommended. How do I put this wkhtmltopdf to my CI library? How do I use it in Codeigniter?

Comment: [whathaveyoutried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a CLI tool so you'll need to add the binary to your server (local, testing, production, etc) and execute with `exec()` or `shell_exec()` while ensuring the destination is writable.

The tool itself takes it's command like so:

```
path/to/wkhtmltopdf url/to/pdf new_file.pdf
```

There are lots of settings. You can review them with:

```
path/to/wkhtmltopdf -extended-help
```

You may be tempted to use some of the PHP wrappers people have put together. I would advise you do not do that. It's caused me nothing but headaches.

Comment: I'm not to familiar with shell or CLI. I have very little knowledge about it since i'm still in the learning process in school. So if you can guide me, that would be a great help.

I am now using CodeIgniter (as I've written in the title), and the server I use is still a testing server with XAMPP. Recently I've used MPDF, so I've put the mpdf inside the ci library. Now my question is whether or not wkhtmltopdf the same principle from mpdf,  if not how can I use wkhtmltopdf in my CI? Could you provide step by step guide, that would be much appriciated...

Comment: First off, grab what you need from the downloads page, and install it. Once you do that, find where you installed it, and run the extended help command. If you do that correctly, you'll see it return a bunch of text. On Windows (Right?) you'll want Start > Run > cmd then type in something like `C:\wkhtmltopdf.exe --extended-help`

Comment: This should work, but I've had some issues with 0.11 rc 1 on my mac: https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/detail?name=wkhtmltox-0.11.0_rc1-installer.exe&can=2&q=

Comment: I'm still confused. But please bear with me because i'm still learning. So I've installed the wkhtmltopdf to windows (currently i'm using windows 8). I've seen the help section, but does that mean that i'm only able to convert it to pdf if I installed the binary first? What if a user (hypothetically if I've had a running server) wanted to print an output in pdf? Do they need to install the binary too?

Comment: A website visitor would click a link, submit a form, or however you set it up, and you would execute the required shell command from Codeigniter, creating the PDF in a writable directory, then serving up that PDF to the visitor. Since that all happens *server side*, you only need the one binary on the server (likely the linux binary in a production environment).

Comment: I see. Now you said linux binary. If im using windows does it still could run? I just have to add the binary to the binary folder in codeigniter? Do i need to impelemnt some kind of class? Eg: mpdf uses a mpdf library with $this->load–>library(mpdf) or do i use shell_exec directly like you said?  But you're right though, using wraper class does not make it easier (i've tried)

Comment: Your development environment is xampp. That's on Windows, so you'd install the Windows wkhtml like you did, and access it via `shell_exec()`. If/when you migrate your codebase to a typical production server, you'll need to add the binary to your `/usr/local/bin` folder or where ever you see fit (outside of CI). Within CI, you should set up different config folders for different environments so you can dynamically change the path in your `shell_exec`. This is getting ahead though.. get it working locally first ;)

Comment: I installed the wkhtmltopdf.exe in /Program Files (x86). but when I run the shell_exec in CI it doesn't show the pdf. I used the test version first to make sure and it still doesnt show.
`shell_exec("C:\Program Files (x86)\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe http://www.google.com google.pdf");` . Why is that?

Comment: It's probably best to start sifting through other questions and/or asking new ones: